# Translating scientific literature

Tags: discussion, resources

My goal in learning Japanese is to translate scientific literature either way into Japanese or English, especially in the realm of immunology, behavioral biology, and natural sciences.

- Does anyone have experience with this? How did you get into the field?
- Are there resources that you found particularly useful in building up your vocabulary, other than reading papers on the topic of interest?

So far the resources I've found on [this forum](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/written-resources-for-scientific-and-philosophic-japanese) and others include:

- [J-STAGE](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/browse/-char/en) for practice reading journals
- Technical Japanese textbook series by Edward Daub/Nobuo Inoue/James Davis

Any other resources you liked?

Comment: I take it you’re already ~native level in Japanese if you’re considering translating both directions? I’ve had good success just talking about various medical topics with folks where I live (Boston, which has a large number of medical researchers and doctors from Japan, to the point that we have a conference and community around it), and medical terminology tends to be fairly intuitive in Japanese (far more so than in English...). If you live in Japan I’d recommend finding opportunities to actually use the terms in discussion. (Obviously reading papers and textbooks is critical too.)